# How to simplify template containing pointer to member, with member in a base class

Tags: c++

I am implementing an intrusive container (no, boost intrusive won't cover my specific use case) and in doing so, I came across the following problem.

The main requirement is that it needs to work on C++14 as C++17 is only now starting to become ubiquitous.

(Whole code is available on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/838e4GGor))

My hook class that container the link information is defined as follows.

```cpp
struct Hook {
    void* next;
};
```

The container class (eg a list) could be defined like

```cpp
template< typename T, Hook T::*hook >
struct Container {
   T* first = nullptr;
   void push_front( T& value ) { 
      (value.*hook).next = first;
      first = &value;
   }
};
```

Then I define a base class that implements a lot of the functionality needed. Note that this class could be indexed by several means, eg by arrival time or by shipment size.

```cpp
template< Traits >
struct Base {
    Hook by_time;
    Hook by_size;
    void check_inventory() {...}
};
```

The instantiation for the application is done in a class with concrete traits.

```cpp
struct Derived : Base<ConcreteTraits> {

};
```

Now if I define my container in the trivial way, I will get the following error

```cpp
Container< Derived, &Derived::by_time > inventory;
...
error: conversion from 'Hook Base<ConcreteTraits>::*' to 'Hook Derived::*' is not allowed in a converted constant expression
   31 |     Container< Derived, &Derived::by_time> ca;                      ^~~~~~~~
```

To solve this issue I have to add one level of class indirection as

```cpp
template< typename T, typename U, Hook U::*hook >
struct Container {
};
```

and then define my container as

```cpp
Container< Derived, Base<ConcreteTraits>, &Derived::by_time> ca;
```

The issue is that this is not only inconvenient, confusing and error prone, but frequently the class `Base` is buried in the library sources and I would not like to disclose it.

Given that the compiler knows the types already, the question is how can I change this framework so I can declare my concrete container as just

```cpp
Container< Derived, &Derived::by_time > ca;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break the lookup dependency by providing accessor methods in the derived class. It's a bit more verbose but it works fine

```cpp
struct Derived : Base<ConcreteTraits> {
    Hook& getTimeHook() {
        return by_time;
    }
    Hook& getSizeHook() {
        return by_size;
    }
};
```

Then the definition of the concrete classes is very simple, as you wished

```cpp
int main() {
    Container< Derived, &Derived::getTimeHook > ct;
    Container< Derived, &Derived::getSizeHook > cs;
}
```

The only change necessary in the container is to call the accessor method instead:

```cpp
template< typename T, Hook& (T::*hookfn)() >
struct Container {
T* first = nullptr;
void push_front( T& value ) { 
    (value.*hookfn()).next = first;
    first = &value;
}
};
```

Code available in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/hGheq6P4T)

This solution works with virtually any compiler and standard version that's not ancient.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of necessitating the conversion of a `Hook Derived::*` to a `Hook Base::*` in a constant expression, you can just make sure that such a conversion is possible.

Change the template-head as follows:

```cpp
template< typename T, std::convertible_to<Hook T::*> auto hook >
struct Container {
   // ...
};

// the syntax Container<Derived, &Derived::member> is now valid
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7ajPzP1Ec).*

You could also consider having a `typename` parameter instead of accepting a data member pointer which acts as a projection, similar to the projections on algorithms in the ranges library. See [`std::ranges::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/find) for example:

```cpp
template < typename T, typename Proj >
struct Container {
    T* first = nullptr;
    [[no_unique_address]] Proj proj{}; // don't waste space for empty classes
    void push_front( T& value ) { 
        std::invoke(proj, value).next = first;
        first = &value;
    }
};
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nsocq5azK)*

Comment: Jan thanks for the answer! I'm currently mandated to use C++14 due to the upstream users and it seems `std::convertible_to` depends on C++20 as well as the auto non-type template. Any ideas?

Comment: @FredHelmers `std::convertible_to` would be easy to imitate with SFINAE and `std::enable_if`. `auto` NTTPs ... not so much. You might just have to go with the approach that use a `typename` parameter instead. It's overall more flexible anyway. It's very idiomatic too; it's exactly what `std::set` does with `typename Compare = std::less<T>` etc.

Comment: I tried that but it's a chicken-and-egg problem, unlike the `std::set` example you gave. The key issue here is to infer the base type.

Comment: @FredHelmers what if you encode the data member pointer as a type? https://godbolt.org/z/Efxs931xT You can still constrain it with SFINAE and whatnot.

Comment: That sounds much more interesting. Do you know how boost::intrusive::slist does it? I'm trying to read that but I'm lost.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with the Boost implementation.